# How to deploy Angular and .NET applications to one folder on IIS?

Tags: .net, angular, iis

I got following problem, I need to host Angular and .NET application in one IIS WebApplication , so folder for WebApplication looks like this:

```
- WebApp
  - (all angular dist files)
  - web.config (for angular)
  - rest
    - (DLL and other .NET files)
    - web.config (for .NET application)
```

When I call https://my-application.com:8187/rest/api/Config I get 405 error, but when I will remove webconfig for angular then REST works fine, but angular app got 404 error after refresh , any ideas what I'm doing wrong? below I provide both web configs

for angular

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="SomeOtherRule" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

for .NET application

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        </customHeaders>
      </httpProtocol>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\MyApp.MyAppPersons.Persons.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Comment: You already see `<location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">` in your second `web.config` file. You need to apply the same to your first `web.config`.

Comment: You can use this link as a reference about how to keep the UI and API in the same place, [https://dotnetblog.asphostportal.com/easy-steps-to-deploy-angular-and-asp-net-core-in-same-iis-folder](https://dotnetblog.asphostportal.com/easy-steps-to-deploy-angular-and-asp-net-core-in-same-iis-folder/).